# Core Data: fetchedResultsController Relationship is "magically" set to nil

Tags: objective-c, core-data

**The Background:**

- I am working in an inventory management app.
- Users can add inventory to a truck
- When adding an item that is already on a truck I just want to update its quantity instead of adding it again.
- It is a one-to-one relationship. For now there is only one "truck"
  [image: Image Description Here]

**The Process Logic**: Once an item number is entered, look for it under *Items*. If found, create the appropriate *truckItem* managed object and keep it in a dictionary. Once I am getting ready to save the context check against all *truckInventory* objects stored. If the item already exists, then get the *truckItem* managed object, and add the quantities, destroy the newly created *truckItem*. Save.

**The Problem**: When checking against the stored truckItems it will load all the information but item will be set to nil. (Note, is nil, not ). Therefore, the quantity reflects the right value, but we no longer have the appropriate item.

**The Simplified Code:**
Loading Inventory:

```
NSError *error;
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"TruckItems"];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"item" ascending:YES];

[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

loadedInventoryResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self->context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

if(![loadedInventoryResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
      NSLog(@"Error! %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Checking Against Saved Inventory Simplified Code:

```
for(NSString *mpn in items) {

    TruckItems *item = [items objectForKey:mpn];

    //This shows the right number of managedObjects, but the ones that are repeated show item = nil;
    NSLog(@"Logged: %@", [loadedInventoryResultsController fetchedObjects]);

    //Check to see if items are already in inventory. If they are update their quantities rather than adding them again.
    for(TruckItems *loadedItem in [loadedInventoryResultsController fetchedObjects]) {

        Items *storedItem = [loadedItem item]; //I am doing this just for testing: This comes back as nil. This is the problem as it comes nil
        Items *scanned = [item item];  //Same here.

                if([stored.manufacturerProductNumber isEqualToString:scanned.manufacturerProductNumber]) {

                    item.quantity = [loadedItem.quantity decimalNumberByAdding:item.quantity];

                    [context deleteObject:loadedItem];
                }
            }
        }
//Save context
```

**The Questions:** Why is it being set to nil? How to avoid it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are going to create tag wikis with copy-and-pasted text from another site, please **cite** the source you are copying from; otherwise, you are [plagiarizing the text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137799/what-to-do-about-large-amounts-of-plagiarizing-in-tag-wikis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If found, create the appropriate truckItem managed object and keep it in a dictionary

"The appropriate" truckItem object must only be one where the`item` relationship is populated with the appropriate `Items` object. Since you have a one-to-one relationship, this will remove the `item` value from any other `truckItem` objects you have.

> add the quantities, destroy the newly created truckItem.

This then deletes the only `truckItem` object with a valid relationship back to the item.

You don't show the code where you make the `truckItem`, but since you're searching through the `Items`, just use the `onTruck` property of the item - this will be nil, if it isn't on the truck, or a truckItem object if it is. At that point, create a new item or update the quantity.

Comment: You know, I thought about it but I thought all the relation and property checking happened when the context was saved, not as managed objects were being created. Thanks for clarifying it.